# bsd sockets connect timeout iPhone

Tags: iphone, c, sockets

How to write code which specifies timeout to BSD sockets `connect` syscall ? I writing iPhone application and i need to wait long time to get response from `connect` syscall. Any Examples ? 
Thanks

Now i have something like this:

```
host_name = NULL ;
host_name = gethostbyname([[host_value hostname] UTF8String]) ; 
if (host_name != NULL)
{
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons([[host_value port_number] intValue]);
    memcpy((char *)&sin.sin_addr,(char*)host_name->h_addr,host_name->h_length);
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)(&sin),sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) != 0) 
    {
       /* code */
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);  
int x;
x=fcntl(s,F_GETFL,0);
fcntl(s,F_SETFL,x | O_NONBLOCK);
```

From: http://rhoden.id.au/doc/sockets2.html